# hibernate.dialect property is not getting identified by my spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have recently made few changes to my project to fix security vulnerablities

Made Spring boot version **3.1.4 to 3.1.6**
and then Spring web: **6.0.13 to 6.0.17** ,
tomcat-embed-core : **10.1.16 to 10.1.19**

Apart from this I didnt make any changes

But I see my application is not running and saying

```
20:10:58.256 [main] ERROR org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')
```

Though I already have the hibernate.dialect defined like this

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

I know of a solution to this problem that I've to define below and its working and the application gets started!!

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

But why is this not working
the above version upgrades have any relevance ?

Comment: You should configure it with: 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect.
Hibernate 6 does try to derive the dialect from the DB, maybe this falsly made you believe that you were setting it? And now there is some change in the DB not being able to retrieve the dialect?

Comment: May be, there is some change in DB which I'm not aware of , Because Im not managing it. anyways solution is to add the property spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
Thank you. Thanks for highlighting that Hibernate 6 tries to pickup dialect from DB.